# excel macro code is skipping every 2nd line

Tags: vba, excel

the below code is to take an employee name, (Column A) andput the range ("A:J") of that row into a new sheet of that employee, if they dont have a sheet, then make one and ad the heading. However, it is skipping every second line, which is causing the line that it is scanning the name on, and the line it is copying from to be different (ie:Employees are going in the wrong sheets, and only 1/2 are getting moved) 
Any help would be great

```
Set rngEmpSales = wsSales.Range("A2", wsSales.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)
Dim wsSales As Worksheet, wsDesSales As Worksheet
Set wsSales = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales")
Dim SalesCount as Range
    For Each SalesCount In rngEmpSales
                On Error Resume Next
                Set wsDesSales = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Trim(SalesCount.Value))
                On Error GoTo 0
                If wsDesSales Is Nothing Then
                   Set wsDesSales = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
                    wsDesSales.Name = SalesCount.Value
                End If
                SalesCount(1 - (SalesCount.Row - 1)).Range("A1:J1").Copy wsDesSales.Range("K2")
                SalesCount.Range("A" & SalesCount.Row & ":J" & SalesCount.Row).Copy wsDesSales.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Set wsDesSales = Nothing
            End If
    Next SalesCount
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code (`F8`)?

Comment: yes my friend, this is how i discovered it, ass things started to slowly go more and more astray.

Comment: if `wsSales` is a worksheet then why are you re declaring it again? How did you declare and set it initially?

Comment: ?? There is a wsSales and a wsDesSales, if that is your confusion, both declarded. Although wsSales not needed for this part of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? (UNTESTED)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsSales As Worksheet, wsDesSales As Worksheet
    Dim rngEmpSales As Range, SalesCount As Range
    Dim shName As String
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    Set wsSales = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales")

    With wsSales
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rngEmpSales = .Range("A2:A" & lRow)

        For i = 2 To lRow
            shName = Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wsDesSales = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shName)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If wsDesSales Is Nothing Then
                Set wsDesSales = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
                wsDesSales.Name = shName
            End If

            .Range("A1:J1").Copy wsDesSales.Range("K2")
            .Range("A" & i & ":J" & i).Copy wsDesSales.Range("K" & _
                                            wsDesSales.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            Set wsDesSales = Nothing
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ive see you round you dont need to test stuff! cheers mate, bang on

Answer (score 0):

You should use

`wssales.Range("A" & SalesCount.Row & ":J" & SalesCount.Row)` instead of `SalesCount.Range("A" & SalesCount.Row & ":J" & SalesCount.Row)`

and

`wssales.Range("A1:J1").Copy` instead of 
`SalesCount(1 - (SalesCount.Row - 1)).Range("A1:J1").Copy`

The reason is `SalesCount` itself is a range, when you apply another `.Range` after it, it will take the relative position.

e.g. `Range("A2").Range("A1:J1")` becomes `Range("A2:J2")` and `Range("B2").Range("B2:K2")` becomes `Range("B2:K2")`